# Visual Studio Error: Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : VsWebSqmFlag

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I just created a simple calculator in C# (.cs) using Notepad++ and uploaded this .cs file in my Visual Studio Online project. But when I click on "Open in Visual Studio 2013", it gives me the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aShl1.png):

> Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : VsWebSqmFlags.
>
> Use: devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]
>
> The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file or project
>   file. You can also use any other file as the first argument if you
>   want to have the file open automatically in an editor. When you enter
>   a project file, the IDE looks for an .sln file with the same base name
>   as the project file in the parent directory for the project file. If
>   no such .sln file exists, then the IDE looks for a single .sln file
>   that references the project. If no such single .sln file exists, then
>   the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln file name that
>   has the same base name as the project file.
>
> Command line builds: devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ]
>   [ /project projectnameorfile [ /projectconfig name ] ] Available
>   command line switches:
>
> /Build    Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
>   configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
>   possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes and
>   contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32". /Clean Deletes
>   build outputs. /Command   Starts the IDE and executes the command.
>   /Deploy   Builds and then deploys the specified build configuration.
>   /Edit Opens the specified files in a running instance of this
>   application. If there are no running instances, it will start a new
>   instance with a simplified window layout. /LCID   Sets the default
>   language in the IDE for the UI. /Log  Logs IDE activity to the
>   specified file for troubleshooting. /NoVSIP   Disables the VSIP
>   developer's license key for VSIP testing. /Out    Appends the build log
>   to a specified file. /Project Specifies the project to build, clean,
>   or deploy. Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
>   /ProjectConfig    Overrides the project configuration specified in the
>   solution configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
>   possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes and
>   contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32". Must be used with
>   /Project. /Rebuild    Cleans and then builds the solution or project with
>   the specified configuration. /ResetAddin  Removes commands and command
>   UI associated with the specified Add-in. /ResetSettings   Restores the
>   IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings
>   file. /ResetSkipPkgs  Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
>   /Run  Compiles and runs the specified solution. /RunExit  Compiles and
>   runs the specified solution then closes the IDE. /SafeMode    Launches
>   the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows. /Upgrade    Upgrades the
>   project or the solution and all projects in it. A backup of these
>   files will be created as appropriate.  Please see Help on 'Visual
>   Studio Conversion Wizard' for more information on the backup process.
>
> Product-specific switches:
>
> /diff Compares two files.  Takes four parameters: SourceFile,
>   TargetFile, SourceDisplayName(optional), TargetDisplayName(optional)
>   /TfsLink  Opens Team Explorer and launches a viewer for the  provided
>   artifact URI if one is registered.

Does anyone know why am I seeing this and how to I get rid of it? I have Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated) installed on my machine

Comment: Copy the error into your question and don't post links to images. Your question won't be helpful to any other future reader with such little informations. [Links will rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) anyway.

Comment: added the entire error description

Comment: @YashSaraiya check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cff40f2-8bae-4da1-97f1-a89b6b2c2d18/cant-open-visual-studio-from-website-httpsmynamevisualstudiocom?forum=TFService)

Comment: I checked the link... although the question is exactly related to mine, the solution doesn't works

Comment: Programming in C# usually requires a .csproj and a .sln file associated with the files you are building.

Comment: How do I create .csproj and .sln file on Visual Studio Online?

Comment: How do you upload the .cs files to VSO? You can try create a blank project in VS, then add your .cs files to this project, check in the whole project to VSO, and check whether you can open from VS.

Comment: I created a project on VSO and then under the code tab I found a folder named BuildProcessTemplates.. I just right-clicked it and selected add file option to upload my .cs file... I guess these steps are wrong... I don't think my .cs file should be in BuildProcessTemplates folder

Comment: @YashSaraiya you are right, you shouldn't add file to BuildProcessTemplates folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty project in VS, then add your .cs files in this project, check in the project to the team project you create in VSO, in this way, you should be able Open in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I don't have an access to the templates for creating a C# app in VS 2013 Shell (Integrated)... infact the templates are not installed in VS and I don't have sufficient rights to install

Comment: since you can't work in VS, why do you want to open the project in VS?

Comment: Where do I open it then? I thought using VSO i will be able to get a feel of IDE that a VS generally is

Comment: I'm afraid there is a misunderstanding, "Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) that works with Visual Studio Online (VSO), a set of complementary cloud services that teams can use to share code, track work, and ship software. When you store your code, tests, and test results using VSO, you can access your code from anywhere with Visual Studio or other development tools, build your app, run tests, and deploy", which means all code modification should be in VS, VSO is used for version control and automatically build, etc.